# How to use "ChangeMap"

Tags: amnesia-the-dark-descent

How can you use this command in your script?

`ChangeMap(string& asMapName, string& asStartPos, string& asStartSound, string& asEndSound);`

I have read [this](https://wiki.frictionalgames.com/hpl2/amnesia/script_functions#engine_scripts), but cannot get it to work.